# MySQL GROUP BY and sort the group by column

Tags: mysql

I want to sort a group by a specific column.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT u.level, max(u.score),n.nick 
FROM database.userdata u, database.nicks n 
WHERE n.user = u.id 
GROUP BY level
```

But this only prints the max score, and not the username for this score..

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your query mentions two tables, but doesn't provide any conditions for joining them together. That means MySQL will consider all possible combinations of rows in the two tables. *Surely* you can find some working examples of using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT n.nick, u1.score, u1.level 
FROM database.nicks AS n
JOIN database.userdata AS u1 ON n.user = u1.id
JOIN (
   SELECT level, max(score) AS score 
   FROM database.userdata 
   GROUP BY level
) AS u2 ON u1.level = u2.level AND u1.score = u2.score
```